# How detect and run a shell script when any file or folder is being copied/moved to a directory?

Tags: command-line, scripts, files

How can I detect any file or folder is being copied/moved to a directory and then run a shell script?

**The files copied/moved would mostly have the same file names as the existing ones...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `inotify`, command line tools provided in `inotify-tools` package.

Also better should be the package `inoticoming`. Description:

```
Description: trigger actions when files hit an incoming directory
 inoticoming is a daemon to watch a directory with Linux's inotify
 framework and trigger actions once files with specific names are placed
 in there.
 .
 For example it can be used to wait for .changes files uploaded
 into a directory and call reprepro to put them into your repository.
```

Comment: Thank you, enzotib but is there a work around if I don't want to install a package? If I want to achieve this without any outside packages?

Comment: In such a case, you should check in a loop the presence of files.

Comment: Thats fine until the files that might be copied / moved have different file names to those inside the directory....what for those which have the same name... i.e. those which get overwritten...

Comment: You could probably check the inode number, with `ls -li`