# How to prevent the deletion (but not the creation) of items in a folder?

Tags: files, directory, delete

There is a folder which is being created within another folder in my home directory, and I want to be able to analyse the contents of this folder, however, I have a problem: as the folder is created, it is then immediately deleted by the same program that creates it. Is there any way that I can allow it to create the folder, but then not to delete it? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you might also want to ask this on Unix & Linux

Comment: @Daniel the "also" is a problem - cross-posting is generally unwelcome.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that ^

Comment: How soon is "immediately"?

Comment: @muru: Less than a second. Just basically a flash.

Comment: Isn't that what the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) is for?

Comment: For humans. You could try using `inotify` (http://askubuntu.com/a/60310/158442) or `incron` (http://askubuntu.com/a/546264/158442) to immediately run `chmod -w` on the parent directory.

Comment: @Jos Sticky bit prohibits deletion by all but the owner, if I remember right. Owner can still delete, if he has write permissions.

Comment: But the program does not need to be the owner of the files it creates.

Comment: I am the owner of the file it creates and I own it (the program).

Comment: How often is the folder created / deleted? Seconds? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: @kos: It is created when I execute something special, I don't know how long it exactly takes to be deleted, but it is literally a flash, less than a second.

Comment: @muru: How exactly do I use and configure those tools?

Comment: But do you have control on its creation? if so a simple loop might do to quickly dump some informations: `while [ ! -d <directory> ]; do sleep 0.1; done; stat <directory> >out`

Comment: @kos: Well, I sort of do... It gets created every time I open a closed-source application that I have installed.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda see update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no permission settings that can do this, even using ACLs, but you can have a race with the program, using `inotifywait`:

In one terminal, I ran:

```bsh
while sleep 0.5; do if mkdir foo/bar; then echo foo; rmdir foo/bar; fi; done
```

As you can see, this creates a directory, echoes a message and removes the directory - all of which happens very quickly by human standards.

And in another:

```bsh
while true
do
    if inotifywait -e create foo
    then
        chmod -w foo
        if [[ -d foo/bar ]]
        then
            break 
        else
            chmod +w foo
        fi
    fi
done
```

This command waits for creation of anything in `foo`, then removes write permissions from `foo`, and tests if it was in time for catching the sub directory. If not, it adds back the write permission, and starts again.

After waiting a bit:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
rmdir: failed to remove ‘foo/bar’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘foo/bar’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘foo/bar’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘foo/bar’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘foo/bar’: File exists
```

This is relying on a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), so whether you can catch it is a matter of luck.

---

`foo/bar` is the directory that the program makes. If you don't know the name of it, you can try other ways:

- ensure that there's nothing else in the directory, so when a subdirectory is created, `foo/` is non-empty. Some tests for non-empty directory are available in [this U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202243/70524):

  ```
  shopt -s nullglob
  if [ -n "$(ls -A foo/)" ]
  then
      break
  ```

  This worked fast enough.
- read the name of the created directory from `inotifywait`'s output:

  ```
  if dir=$(inotifywait -e create --format '%f' foo)
  then
      chmod -w foo
      if [[ -d foo/$dir ]]
  ```

  This didn't work (yet) for me; the overhead of creating subshell seems to make it just sufficiently slow enough for the other loop to win each time. Maybe coded in C using the `inotify` API, this could work.

Comment: The directory won't be empty, and if I empty it I could break the mechanism which creates this mystery folder.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda how would you do that?

Comment: How could I do what?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda "break the mechanism which creates this mystery folder"?

Comment: This folder is filled with configuration files for the application in question and it can't start to perform any action without them.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda does it create anything else?